# Match a UPN list to assigned VM names using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, wvd

I am trying to pass a list of UPNs in to a function to find all Sessionhosts (Virtual Machines) assigned to that UPN in Azure WVD. I would like to match those sessionhost names to the UPN in the list I am passing through and it's just beyond my skill level at this moment. Thank you to anyone who may be able to help me.

The input looks like this.

```
email1  
email2
```

Output looks like this.

```
vmname1  
vmname2  
othervmname1  
othervmname2
```

The output I'd love to be able to figure out would be to create an array, or something, with two columns where id have the output like so:

```
email1 : vmname1  
email1 : vmname2  
email2 : othervmname1  
email2 : othervmname2
```

My code is below.

```
Add-RdsAccount -DeploymentUrl "https://rdbroker.wvd.microsoft.com" | Out-Null
 
$upnlist = get-content -path c:\path\to\upnlist.txt
 
#Function to find the session hosts the user is a part of in the WVD Fall 2019 environment.
function Get-FallSessionName {
           
    $Tenants = "tenant,tenant2,tenant3"
    
    ForEach ($upn in $upnlist) {
       
        ForEach ($Tenant in $Tenants) {
           
            $Hostpools = (Get-RdsHostPool -TenantName $Tenant).HostPoolName
           
            foreach ($Hostpool in $Hostpools) {  
                    
                (Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName $Tenant -HostPoolName $Hostpool | where-object {$_.AssignedUser -eq $upn}).SessionHostName)
            }
        }      
    }
    Return $SessionHostName
}
 
 
$2019SessionNames = Get-FallSessionName
 
$2019SessionNames | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Create a ps custom object (and then add those to an array) or create a hashtable

Comment: Can you give me a generic example of how to do that? That's kind of what I assumed but I don't have experience doing that.

Comment: google is your friend ;) [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.1) [pscustomobject](https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/15/4-ways-to-create-powershell-objects/)

Comment: take a look at the links they provide generic examples

Comment: I genuinely apologize. New to stackoverflow and didn't realize links were there and have been frustrated with this. Thought I got a RTFM reply with no help so I popped off. Thank you for your links.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no way to try this function and see if it works as expected, I have modified your code and gave you a few hints.

***IMPORTANT*** I'm not 100% sure that the property `AssignedUser` of [`Get-RdsSessionHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/get-rdssessionhost) will return a `UserPrincipalName`. You would need to evaluate your code in case it is returning something different.

Try and see if it works:

```
Add-RdsAccount -DeploymentUrl "https://rdbroker.wvd.microsoft.com" | Out-Null
 
$upnlist = get-content -path c:\path\to\upnlist.txt

function Get-FallSessionName {
param(
    [string[]]$UserPrincipalName,
    [string[]]$Tenants
)

    ForEach ($Tenant in $Tenants)
    {
        $Hostpools = (Get-RdsHostPool -TenantName $Tenant).HostPoolName
        Foreach ($Hostpool in $Hostpools)
        {
            # This should find all the Hosts where the property 'AssignedUser' is equal to ANY
            # item on the 'UserPrincipalName' array.
            $sessionHosts = (Get-RdsSessionHost -TenantName $Tenant -HostPoolName $Hostpool |
                where-object {$_.AssignedUser -in $UserPrincipalName}).SessionHostName
            
            # Since Get-RdsSessionHost can return multiple SessionHostNames we need to
            # loop through the possible array $sessionHosts
            foreach($hostName in $sessionHosts)
            {
                # Here is where you can define how your object should look like

                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Tenant=$Tenant
                    HostPool=$Hostpool
                    SessionHostName=$hostName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# -> This is how your function should be called. Parameters should not be hardcoded inside a function
$2019SessionNames = Get-FallSessionName -UserPrincipalName $upnlist -Tenants 'tenant','tenant2','tenant3'
$2019SessionNames | Out-GridView
```

`$2019SessionNames` should look like this:

| Tenant | HostPool | SessionHostName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tenant1 | HostPool1 | user.example@domain.com |
| Tenant2 | HostPool2 | user.example2@domain.com |

Comment: Oh TIL about calling a function like that. I'm sure that's a simple thing that most know but it never occurred to me to call to it that way inside of a script so that is really useful. Thanks for that and I think that works after making some super small adjustments. That example of a pscustomobject makes more sense in my brain too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jsolj3x That's good to know, feel free to [edit my post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67302579/edit) with your adjustments so anyone can find it helpful in the future :)

Comment: What you have is correct and works great. So this is answered. Thank you again.